# Android cloud endpoint: Entity key as data value of other entity

Tags: android, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a App Engine Java project with an entity of the form

```
@Entity
public class UserDB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userName;
}

@Entity
public class HistoryDB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @ManyToOne
    private Key userId; //Key from the UserDB

    public Key getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(Key key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public Key getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(Key userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

The client endpoint library generated by eclipse for the Android end generates multiple `Key.java` files for each entity thus making having the above scheme difficult as the Key of `UserDB` is un-usable as a parameter for the `userID` key in the `HistoryDB`.

How can I tackle this?

Also I have similar situation while using the Key from the `HistoryDB` in another database as a data value. In the `UserDB` I have the option to user the username as a unique key in `HistoryDB` but how do I get a unique of `HistoryDB` in the other database?

Comment: If you have a relationship you don't pass around "Key" objects, you use UserDB in HistoryDB. Otherwise remove the ManyToOne annotation

Comment: The idea for having keys was similar to the traditional rdbms systems that keep keys as foreign to store relationships. Any clue for how does it work internally when for example i use UserDb inside HistoryDb? Also how will removing ManyToOne help here?

Comment: ManyToOne says "this is a JPA relationship". What is there is not. This is the O-O world, not an RDBMS world. Go to Google's own tests for such things http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Ftests%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine%2Fdatanucleus%2Ftest%2Fjpa

Comment: Thanks Neil. So if I understood correctly, it will be changed to just `private UserDb userDb` inside `HistoryDb` without the @ManyToOne? Also will there be value in using @JoinColumn(name = "Key") in this situation ?

Comment: No. If you put a real relation there (private UserDB userDb) then you need ManyToOne since its a relation. If you insist on this key stuff then you CANNOT have ManyToOne

Comment: Im not really hard set on the 'Key' thing. Its the first time im doing any server side stuff outside Android, so im not really sure how these things really work. In any case the Key thing is giving me issues.

The idea is that `HistoryDB` is going to be a history of user activity in the app so each entry will be associated with a user and additional data regarding that action. Why I added `@ManytoOne` was thinking that each User is going to have multiple entries in this table for each event he makes. How do you think I can design the `HistoryDB` for this purpose?